# Examples of affine functions and convex sets

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm just learning about convexity and affineness, and I've read over some similar questions asked here, but those were more about general properties. I need some help applying those properties to a few examples that I can't seem to understand. I'd like to see how to show:

1. $C_{1} =  \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid h(x) = 0 \rbrace $ is convex iff $h(x)$ is affine in $C_{1}$
2. $C_{2} =  \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid g(x) \leq 0 \rbrace $ is convex if $g(x)$ is convex on $C_{2}$
3. $C_{3} =  \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid h_{i}(x) = 0,i=1,\ldots,m;\,g_{j}(x) \leq 0,j=1,\ldots,l \rbrace$ is convex if each $h_{i}(x)  $ is affine and each $g_{j}(x)$ is convex in $C_{3}$

So far, for (1), I think I can assume $\forall x \in C_{1}, h(x)=a^{T}x+b $ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$  and $b \in \mathbb{R}$ but I'm not 100% on where to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.$\rightarrow$. Assume that $C_1$ is convex. Then by definition $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_ix_i \in C_1,$$ for all $x_i \in C_1$ and nonnegative numbers $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ such that $\sum \lambda_i=1.$ Then
 $$h\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_ix_i\big)=0=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_ih(x_i),$$ 
where both sides are equal to zero due to the definition of $C_1$ and the fact that $x_i \in C_1$ as well as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_ix_i \in C_1$.
So $h$ is affine (check in wikipedia the alternative definition of affineness. I use it in the next direction).

2.$\leftarrow$. Assume $h$ is affine. Then by definition $$h\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_ix_i\big)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_ih(x_i),$$
for all $x_i \in C_1$ and nonnegative numbers $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ such that $\sum \lambda_i=1.$ Then $$h\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_ix_i\big)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_ih(x_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_1\cdot0=0,$$
Thus,$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i(x_i) \in C_1$ and therefore $C_1$ is convex.

Comment: Analogously proceed with 2 and 3. If you have a problem let me know.

Comment: So, I would think that to start off for (1), you'd have to start with the affineness assumption first? As in prove convexity by using $h(x)$'s affine nature?

Comment: You have to show two directions. Firstly that convexiry implies affineness and secondly that affineness implies convexity or vise versa. The order in which you will do it is not important. Is that what you asked?

Comment: I guess so, yeah, I just read the problem as: show that the set $C_{1}$ is convex if and only if $h(x)$ is affine in $C_{1}$. Which in my mind just means start with showing convexity, sorry, I'm a newb here hah

Comment: If and only if means that you have to show two implications. But the order is not important.

Comment: Ok, so I've been trying to apply this to parts 2 and 3, and I'm just getting confused. I don't understand 3 at all, kind of lost with having two functions.

Comment: I understand that if the sets are both convex then $C_{3}$ should also be convex, but I'm having a hard time showing it

Comment: $C_3$ is the intersection of $C_1$ and $C_2$, which you have already prooved that they are covnex. So you only that the intersection of convex sets is again convex, which you can found in many internet sources, f.e. here http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_of_Convex_Sets_is_Convex_Set_%28Vector_Spaces%29